# I have two datepicker from and to i want to Set next year into to datepicker

Tags: jquery, html, datepicker

I have two datepicker i.e From and To

[see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWpFC.png)

What i want to when i select month and year from From datepicker and in To datepicker automatically set months and year but year should be plus one

**HTML**

```
<label for="startDate">From :</label>
<input name="startDate"id="startDate" class="date-pickerfrom" />

<label for="startDate">To :</label>
<input name="startDate"id="startDate" class="date-pickerto" />
```

**CSS**

```
.ui-datepicker-calendar {
     display: none;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
  $(function() {
      $('.date-pickerfrom').datepicker( {
           changeMonth: true,
           changeYear: true,
           showButtonPanel: true,
           dateFormat: 'MM yy',
           onClose: function(dateText, inst) { 
                var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
                var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
                $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
           }
      });
  });

 $(function() {
     $('.date-pickerto').datepicker( {
          changeMonth: true,
          changeYear: true,
          showButtonPanel: true,
          dateFormat: 'MM yy',
          onClose: function(dateText, inst) { 
              var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
              var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
              $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(+year, month, 1));
        }
    });
});
```

[See Code](http://jsfiddle.net/Lxj5u92o/3/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just extending your `onClose` in your code to set todate

```
onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
  var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
  var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();

  var fDate = new Date(year, month, 1)
  $(this).datepicker('setDate', fDate);

  var tDate = new Date(fDate.setFullYear(fDate.getFullYear() + 1));
  $(".date-pickerto").datepicker("setDate", tDate)
}
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/aswinkumar863/8L4xqrkg/11/)